# Who was Jack talking to?

Tags: he-never-died

Jack, the main character in He Never Died sometimes notices a person in a hat that not everyone around him can see for whatever reason. I suppose the movie has a lot of biblical context but I'm not very educated in that, so I don't get a lot of it. Who was that person? Why did they appear? What happened in the final scene of the movie where the bad guy suddenly could see that person?

Answer (score 2):

I just watched this movie last night. This most specific clues for the man's identity come from the end of the movie, so I'm treating it like a spoiler.

> During an exchange at the end of the movie between Jack and the bad guy, the man in the hat appears. When Jack is yelling at the man in the hat, Jack talks about God as if God is a third party and a female. So, the man is likely not God. Later in the scene, Jack turns to the main bad guy and tells him "One day, you'll see who I was talking to." Right after Jack exits, the bad guy turns and actually sees the man in the hat for the first time. The man has dark black eyes and speaks in a demonic voice, so it seems fairly straightforward to say that the man is likely Lucifer.

[Script for "He Never Died" >>](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=he-never-died)