# Is Jack not allowed to redeem himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, he-never-died

At the end of the movie *He Never Died* (2015), Jack is building up to kill Alex, when he is "stopped" by an Old Man at the bar, implied to be [Death](https://www.reddit.com/r/netflix/comments/5ae1q2/would_someone_be_so_kind_to_explain_he_never_died/) or [Lucifer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45340/who-was-jack-talking-to). Jack then proceeds to have a one-sided conversation with him about not being allowed to kill Alex

> What? Why? Why now? For him? That man's a murderer and he's aware of it! The world would be a better
>   place if I killed him, right now. I've tortured thousands of innocent people to death... and you weren't around for them! You weren't even around for Egypt. Or Walachilla! I impaled thousands of people in Walachilla just see them die.

Shortly after, the Old Man turns to Alex, seemingly having just appeared to him. Either way, it seems Alex wasn't far from Death's door. So why did the Old Man stop Jack? Is he unable to redeem himself, as part of his punishment?